# WebPack TypeScript React module not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

So let me start my saying I am fairly new to WebPack and React, but I have something basic working (at least it works in the browser). I am however an ok C# developer, so want to use Visual Studio as my editor of choice. I have created a fairly simple webpack setup and created a dummy solution file (Visual Studio 2015 update 3), where I have created a web site from file system.

I have a working (in the browser) Webpack + TypeScript + React + Babel setup which as I say works famously in the browser. It is largely based on the official guidelines for using TypeScript with React https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

I have followed that tutorial to the letter and even though it runs in the browser just fine also suffers from the same issue as my richer webpack setup.

**So what is the issue exactly?**
The main issue is that my setup doesn't seem to recognise "React" as a valid module import inside of a TSX file (even though everything is fine in the browser).

I have have read so many posts that talk about different Webpack settings, and tsconfig.json settings that my head is spinning.

I thought it might be better to show you some of my files to see if anyone knows how to fix my issue

**.babelrc**

```
{ "presets": ["es2015"] }
```

**package.json** (I am using NPM)

```
{
  "name": "task1webpackconfig",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "webpack 2 + TypeScript 2 + Babel example",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/sachabarber/MadCapIdea.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "babel",
    "typescript",
    "webpack",
    "bundling",
    "javascript",
    "npm"
  ],
  "author": "sacha barber",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/sachabarber/MadCapIdea#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^15.0.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.63",
    "@types/react": "^15.0.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015-native-modules": "^6.9.4",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "typescript": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
let _ = require('lodash');
let webpack = require('webpack');
let path = require('path');

let babelOptions = {
    "presets": ["es2015"]
};

function isVendor(module) {
    return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
}

let entries = {
    index: './index.tsx'
};

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry: entries,
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    devServer: {
        open: true, // to open the local server in browser
        contentBase: __dirname,
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"]
        //modulesDirectories: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    },

    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          names: ['vendor'],
          minChunks: function (module, count) {
              // creates a common vendor js file for libraries in node_modules
              return isVendor(module);
          }
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          name: "commons",
          chunks: _.keys(entries),
          minChunks: function (module, count) {
              // creates a common vendor js file for libraries in node_modules
              return !isVendor(module) && count > 1;
          }
      })
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader' 1st 
            // then 'babel-loader'
            // NOTE : loaders run right to left (think of them as a cmd line pipe)
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                  {
                      loader: 'babel-loader',
                      options: babelOptions
                  },
                  {
                      loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
                  }
                ]
            },

            // All files with a '.js' extension will be handled by 'babel-loader'.
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                  {
                      loader: 'babel-loader',
                      options: babelOptions
                  }
                ]
            },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

When I run webpack all seems fine

[image]

Some of you may be wondering about my project structure which looks like this

[image]

And let me just show you that the typings for React/ReactDom are also present

[image]

Like I say when I run this, all seems ok, I get what I expect

1. A working react web page
2. A set of bundle files (which Index.html uses)
3. A Source map for my code

So this tells me the **React** module can be loaded by webpack/browser are working ok.

But when I try and edit the TSX (typescript JSX files) I see this

[image]

Typescript is 100% working for my own files, just cant seem to see **React** stuff.

[image]

Like I say I have tried so many suggested fixes and none have worked, please help me someone

Comment: React & React-Dom type declarations are mentioned in both dependencies and dev-dependencies why is that?

Comment: Um like I say I'm new to this,,could that be the issue?

Comment: I don't think it would be causing the react import to fail but to clarify you only need typescript definition dependencies as dev dependencies. You will also want to add @types/lodash to your dev dependencies.

Comment: In your webpack.config.js, although you can, you shouldn’t need to specify “babel-options” as you have already declared a “.babelrc” file. 
Also, you will want to install “babel-preset-react” and add that to your .babelrc presets e.g. 
      "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react"
      ],

Comment: Nick, I will give this a go on the morning and report back with findings

Comment: Nick, I did all that but sadly the issue remains. Thanks for taking time to give advise though

Comment: remove `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` option from the config file

Comment: @sacha just remove React & React-Dom typings from `dependencies` section and only keep them in `devdependencies`. Then try `npm uninstall *` to clean up your node_modules folder and then install them. If no luck you can give a custom typescript.tsdk path to tell IDE to use the specified typescript version instead of default it has

Comment: @niba removing that allowSyntheticDefaultImports didnt work. :-(

Comment: @KeshShan I did most of what you said already in response to other proposals above. I have NOT tried the  typescript.tsdk I will look into that next. So far though nothing seems to work. Could this be anything to do with the Weback.config.js modules: `[path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"]` stuff?

Comment: I was wondering if your IDE has tooltips when you hover over the code warnings? If it does could you post what it, says? or just Google it :)  Also if your node_modules folder is all up to date then perhaps adding `"lib": ['es6', 'dom' ]` to the compiler options `tsconfig.json`, see if that helps. .. I am just guesing  :) it is difficult to say, with out an error message.

Comment: Yeah no tooltips or error message but I upgraded from visual studio 2015 to 2017 didn't change anything else and it all started working